# Three.js - 2D + 3D Meshes

Tags: javascript, three.js

Is posible to use Canvas2D to draw in the scene? Or, to be more precise, is posible to draw shapes and/or meshes which are independent of the position/rotation/zoom of the camera. We need to do some drawing in the application(not a GUI, as there are already Three.js components available for that functionality).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can draw multiple scenes in three.js.  If you want a static scene that has a few objects and doesn't move with another scenes camera/lights/etc - just make two:

```
        window.scene = new THREE.Scene()
        window.sceneStatic = new THREE.Scene()
```

There's an example of Chrome Experiments doing this in their population globe.  They're using a second scene to do a atmosphere glow around the globe: http://workshop.chromeexperiments.com/globe/